# clear item from player's inventory

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
/summon Item ~ ~3 ~ {CustomName:"banana",CustomNameVisible:1,Item:{id:dye,Damage:11,Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"banana",Lore:[Good to your body!]}}},Age:100000}
```

This command will drop a dye named "banana" and with Lore.

How do I use the `/clear` command to clear this item from a player's inventory?

Answer (score 2):

`/clear` syntax:

```
/clear <player> [id] [Damage] [maximum amount] {dataTags}
```

The dataTags for `/clear` start directly within the `tag` compound, as the rest of the data (minus `Count` and `Slot`) is specified within the command's syntax already.

```
/clear @p minecraft:dye 11 -1 {display:{Name:"banana",Lore:[Good to your body!]}}
```

---

Your command itself is malformed. `Age` is a Short tag, with a range between -32768 and 32767, of which your input greatly exceeds this and will overflow to -31072. If the `Age` tag of an item is 6000 or higher, the item will despawn, which does not appear to be what you want to have happen.

You should not just toss in a random high value for data because it will not function as you expect it to.

If you want an item to never despawn, you can set it to -32768 which will cause it to be locked at that value.

```
/summon Item ~ ~3 ~ {CustomName:"banana",CustomNameVisible:1,Item:{id:"minecraft:dye",Damage:11s,Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"banana",Lore:["Good to your body!"]}}},Age:-32768s}
```